# SKAudionode and Swift3

Tags: swift, xcode8, skaudionode

it been a year since I open my Xcode project and I see that there are some errors.

Now I'm having problem with my audio code. it use to work good a year ago but now it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ0hu.png)

Comment: Post your code snippet as text in your answer instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

```
   self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("MexicanPause.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
```

I don't know where you're trying to implement your code, but this can be add in `touchesBegan` or maybe even `touchesEnded`.